How to speed up large number of calls of a pulp optimization fnction
I have a pulp function that optimizes an objective function based on relationship between two arrays.  In its simplest form the objective function acts on two 1D arrays x and y each of size 20.  The function returns and array of size 20.  The next level of complexity is where x and y both are 2D with dimension 20 x 100.  This means the pulp function need to be called 100 times and the expected return array is 20 x 100.
I have managed to call the pup function in the 2D case as follows:
results = list(map(pulp_fn, x[:, :], y[:, :]))
The final level of complexity is where x and y both are 3D arrays of size N x 20 x 100.  Now, the pulp function need to be called as follows:
for n in range(N):
for s in range(100):
result = pulp_fun(x[n, :, s], y[n, :, s])
I have run with for loops as above but the performance is not good.  I am looking for correct usage of map function or any other method to improve performance. Appreciate any help.
Here is gist of code ....
In the context of the code, here's the problem I am facing.  The code works fine for single run with inputs of num_months x 1 arrays of buy and sell prices.  But performance is quite slow for the case of running the code for N days and s scenarios.  That is, for each of the N days num_months x 1 buy and sell prices arrays for each of the S scenarios are supplied to the function with expected return array of size N x num_months x 2 x Scenarios.  Note that for each run the function returns num_months x 2 array.
# ----------- IMPORTS --------------------------------------------------
import numpy as np
from pulp import *
# ----------- END OF IMPORTS ---------------------------------------------


def revenue_max(buy_prices, sell_prices, num_months, capacity, max_buy, max_sell, start_inventory, reqd_end_inventory):
    """
    Optimizes buy and sell quantities for next budget period
    Parameters:
    buy_prices: num_months x 1 array of floats; 
    sell_prices: num_months x 1 array of floats; 
    capacity: decimal integer; inventory capacity
    max_buy: decimal integer; max for each month
    max_sell: decimal integer; max for each month
    start_inventory: anticipated inventory at start of budget period
    reqd_end_inventory: requirement on budget period end inventory
    Constraints:
    inventory: nx1 floats; inventory >= 0; inventory <= capacity
    buy: optimal buy for each month; buy >= 0; buy <= max_buy
    sell: optimal sell  for each month; sell >= 0; sell <= max_sell
    buy and sell same month not allowed
    Returns:
    buy_sell: schedule of number of buys and sells for each month
    maximum profit
    """

    M = 1000000     # BIG M
    all_data = np.zeros((num_months, 3))

    # ###################################
    period_start_inventory = np.zeros(num_months)
    period_end_inventory = np.zeros(num_months)
    daily_end_inv = np.zeros(shape=(num_months, 31))

    # Creating the lists to be exported to MS Excel file through pandas dataframe
    buyValue = list()
    sellValue = list()
    iValue = list()
    gValue = list()

    budget_horizon = list(range(num_months))
    # #########################Defining the variables########################
    buy = LpVariable.matrix("buy", budget_horizon, 0, None,
                            LpInteger)  # Variable-1 to 24.Injection quantity during time t
    sell = LpVariable.matrix("sell", budget_horizon, 0, None,
                             LpInteger)  # Variable-25 to 48.Withdrawal quantity during time t
    inv = LpVariable.matrix("inv", budget_horizon, 0, None,
                            LpInteger)  # Variable-49 to 72.Inventory in hand at the beginning of time t
    z = LpVariable.matrix("z", budget_horizon, 0, 1,
                          LpBinary)  # Variable-73 to 96.Inventory in hand at the beginning of time t
    # ##########################Objective function (Max. expected profit)############################
    prob = LpProblem(name="Buy_Sell_Schedule", sense=LpMaximize)
    prob += (lpSum([-buy_prices[t] * buy[t] +
                    sell_prices[t] * sell[t]
                    for t in
                    budget_horizon]))
    # ############################Defining the constraints#########################################
    for t in list(range(num_months)):
        prob += sell[t] <= M * z[t]
        prob += buy[t] <= M * (1 - z[t])
        prob += inv[t] <= capacity

        if t > 0:
            b = t - 1
            # buy
            prob += (buy[t] <= capacity - inv[b])
            # sell
            prob += (sell[t] <= inv[b])
            # inventory
            prob += inv[t] == inv[b] + buy[t] - sell[t]  # ORIGINAL

    # Period-0 buy constraint
    prob += (buy[0] <= capacity - start_inventory)

    # Period-0 sell constraint
    prob += (sell[0] <= start_inventory)

    # Period-0 inventory constraint
    prob += (inv[0] == buy[0] - sell[0] + start_inventory)

    # last budget period month constraints
    prob += inv[num_months - 1] == inv[num_months - 2] + buy[num_months - 1] - sell[
        num_months - 1]
    prob += inv[num_months - 1] >= reqd_end_inventory
    prob += inv[num_months - 1] <= reqd_end_inventory

    # ###############################Solving with default cbc solver###################################
    prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False))
    # prob.solve(GLPK_CMD(msg=False))
    # ################################################t##################
    # Extracting the required variables from the model output
    for t in list(range(num_months)):  # budget_horizon:
        buyValue.append(str(buy[t].varValue))  # Injection quantities
        sellValue.append(str(sell[t].varValue))  # withdrawal quantities
        if t == 0:
            inv[t] = (buy[t].varValue - sell[t].varValue + start_inventory)
        else:
            inv[t] = inv[t - 1] + (buy[t].varValue - sell[t].varValue)
        iValue.append(inv)
        g = (-buy[t].varValue * buy_prices[t] + sell[t].varValue * sell_prices[t])  # Monthly cashflow
        gValue.append(g)
       
    buy_qty = np.array(buyValue, dtype=float)
    sell_qty = np.array(sellValue, dtype=float)
    schedule_price = np.where(buy_qty > 0, buy_prices,
                           np.where(sell_qty > 0, sell_prices, 0))

    # --- start and end inventory for each month
    period_start_inventory[0] = start_inventory
    period_end_inventory[0] = period_start_inventory[0] + buy_qty[0] - sell_qty[0]
    for j in range(1, num_months):
        period_start_inventory[j] = period_end_inventory[j - 1]
        period_end_inventory[j] = period_start_inventory[j] + buy_qty[j] - sell_qty[j]

    buy_sell_qty = np.where((buy_qty > 0), -buy_qty, np.where(sell_qty > 0, sell_qty, 0))

    # CASH_FLOWS
    # --- multiply volumes by schedule prices to get cash flows
    monthly_cash_flows_schedule = buy_sell_qty * schedule_price

    # COLLECT ALL RETURN DATA ---- dimension = num_months x 1
    all_data[:, 0] = buy_sell_qty  
    all_data[:, 1] = monthly_cash_flows_schedule

    return all_data


Here's a guide which explains how to add formatted code to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.  Also you should add the Python tag to this I think.

Please write a minimum reproducible example. Until that time this question is off-topic and may be closed.

This is still incomplete, and now also inconsistent. You show how some pulp_fun might be called, but don't show how revenue_max may be called, and it has a different signature for which you don't show any example parameter values.

Sorry about the confusion in not using consistent function name.  The revenue_max function is the function I referred to in the original question.  As I mentioned in the original question, in 3D case the function is called as follows:                                  for n in range(N): for s in range(100): result = revenue_max(buy_prices[n, :, s], sell_prices[n, :, s], num_months, capacity, max_buy, max_sell, start_inventory, reqd_end_inventory)

The code is a mix of redundant, inefficient, and incorrect.
Delete the parameters (max_buy, etc.) that are unused, as well as all of the unused variables in the function.
all_data is the wrong shape. You give it three columns but only use two.
Use empty() instead of zeros() when appropriate.
Instead of an lpSum of products, call lpDot.
Due to shape problems, the code does not run at all unless you squeeze() some of your arrays and/or change your dimension definitions so that there are no 1-dimensions.
M is too large but I do not have the domain visibility to suggest a more appropriate value.
Add unit tests.
You partially describe a "2D case" but show nothing about the meanings of x and y, nor do you define pulp_fn, so I ignore this part of the question. You also say

the pulp function need to be called 100 times

It doesn't need to be called 100 times if you construct a single problem, but you haven't shown enough information for the problem scale to be clear. If startup time of the solver is a problem, then milp is faster but needs more work to construct sparse matrices.
All together,
import numpy as np
import pulp


def revenue_max(
    buy_prices: np.ndarray,   # num_months array of floats
    sell_prices: np.ndarray,  # num_months array of floats
    capacity: int,            # decimal integer; inventory capacity
    start_inventory: int,     # anticipated inventory at start of budget period
    reqd_end_inventory: int,  # requirement on budget period end inventory
) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Optimizes buy and sell quantities for next budget period
    Returns: schedule of number of purchases and sales for each month
    """

    M = 1_000_000     # BIG M
    num_months = buy_prices.size
    budget_horizon = range(num_months)

    # Variables
    buy = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='buy', indices=budget_horizon, cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0, upBound=None,
    )  # Injection quantity during time t
    sell = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='sell', indices=budget_horizon, cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0, upBound=None,
    )  # Withdrawal quantity during time t
    inv = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='inv', indices=budget_horizon, cat=pulp.LpInteger, lowBound=0, upBound=None,
    )  # Inventory in hand at the beginning of time t
    inv_z = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
        name='z', indices=budget_horizon, cat=pulp.LpBinary,
    )  # Inventory in hand at the beginning of time t

    # Objective function (Max. expected profit)
    prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='Buy_Sell_Schedule', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
    prob.setObjective(
        pulp.lpDot(sell_prices, sell) - pulp.lpDot(buy_prices, buy)
    )

    """
    Constraints:
    inventory: nx1 floats; inventory >= 0; inventory <= capacity
    buy: optimal buy for each month; buy >= 0; buy <= max_buy
    sell: optimal sell  for each month; sell >= 0; sell <= max_sell
    buy and sell same month not allowed
    """
    for t in range(num_months):
        prob.addConstraint(name=f'buy_{t}', constraint=buy[t] <= M*(1 - inv_z[t]))
        prob.addConstraint(name=f'sell_{t}', constraint=sell[t] <= M*inv_z[t])
        prob.addConstraint(name=f'inventory_{t}', constraint=inv[t] <= capacity)

        if t > 0:
            b = t - 1
            prob.addConstraint(name=f'buy_prev_{t}', constraint=buy[t] <= capacity - inv[b])
            prob.addConstraint(name=f'sell_prev_{t}', constraint=sell[t] <= inv[b])
            prob.addConstraint(name=f'inventory_prev_{t}', constraint=inv[t] == inv[b] + buy[t] - sell[t])  # ORIGINAL

    prob.addConstraint(name='period_0_buy', constraint=buy[0] <= capacity - start_inventory)
    prob.addConstraint(name='period_0_sell', constraint=sell[0] <= start_inventory)
    prob.addConstraint(name='period_0_inventory', constraint=inv[0] == buy[0] - sell[0] + start_inventory)

    # last budget period month constraints
    prob.addConstraint(name='period_n_buy', constraint=inv[-1] == inv[-2] + buy[-1] - sell[-1])
    prob.addConstraint(name='period_n_inventory', constraint=inv[num_months - 1] == reqd_end_inventory)

    prob.solve()

    buy_qty = np.array([v.value() for v in buy])
    sell_qty = np.array([v.value() for v in sell])
    buy_sell_qty = sell_qty - buy_qty

    schedule_price = np.where(
        buy_qty > 0,
        buy_prices,
        np.where(sell_qty > 0, sell_prices, 0),
    )

    # cash_flows - multiply volumes by schedule prices to get cash flows
    monthly_cash_flows_schedule = buy_sell_qty*schedule_price

    # collect all return data - dimension = num_months x 2
    all_data = np.stack((buy_sell_qty, monthly_cash_flows_schedule), axis=1)
    return all_data


def test() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    n_months = 90
    result = revenue_max(
        buy_prices=rand.uniform(low=1, high=3, size=n_months),
        sell_prices=rand.uniform(low=2, high=4, size=n_months),
        capacity=20,
        start_inventory=15,
        reqd_end_inventory=5,
    )
    expected = np.array([
       [ -5.        , -11.36961687],
       [ 20.        ,  78.7170476 ],
       [-20.        , -21.63894096],
       [ 20.        ,  74.54560361],
       [-20.        , -52.53080957],
       [ 20.        ,  78.28840718],
       [-20.        , -44.26543103],
       [ 20.        ,  78.90515255],
       [-20.        , -41.74499966],
       [ 20.        ,  72.8949531 ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [-20.        , -20.10954001],
       [ 20.        ,  72.07522315],
       [-20.        , -21.34342301],
       [ 20.        ,  50.64521089],
       [-20.        , -27.02622482],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 20.        ,  77.24069264],
       [-20.        , -31.98847562],
       [ 20.        ,  69.28024783],
       [-20.        , -21.13278685],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 20.        ,  68.76879091],
       [-20.        , -45.88758046],
       [ 20.        ,  70.31804009],
       [-20.        , -35.34710217],
       [ 20.        ,  77.16416883],
       [-20.        , -59.23341355],
       [ 20.        ,  73.65269118],
       [-20.        , -46.01837105],
       [ 20.        ,  53.77239915],
       [-20.        , -35.55685696],
       [ 20.        ,  78.64248323],
       [-20.        , -48.85953361],
       [ 20.        ,  50.35458373],
       [-20.        , -32.40967502],
       [ 20.        ,  75.52473283],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [-20.        , -34.31180787],
       [ 20.        ,  63.44492259],
       [-20.        , -32.87477564],
       [ 20.        ,  72.38843104],
       [-20.        , -33.51644902],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 20.        ,  56.51585371],
       [-20.        , -29.08630374],
       [ 20.        ,  65.0602585 ],
       [-20.        , -23.36061374],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 20.        ,  62.10446042],
       [-20.        , -29.57477772],
       [ 20.        ,  73.93164833],
       [-20.        , -22.34272139],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 20.        ,  76.39835847],
       [-20.        , -38.01357467],
       [ 20.        ,  72.90825121],
       [-20.        , -29.22568836],
       [ 20.        ,  73.19215941],
       [-20.        , -36.18207359],
       [ 20.        ,  54.60184631],
       [-20.        , -23.63012182],
       [ 20.        ,  66.10458305],
       [-20.        , -31.94784531],
       [ 20.        ,  68.10608283],
       [-20.        , -27.98061776],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 20.        ,  74.59113182],
       [-20.        , -24.21981118],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 20.        ,  57.19096245],
       [-20.        , -37.61508619],
       [ 20.        ,  79.05849288],
       [-20.        , -39.99583255],
       [ 20.        ,  52.35429451],
       [-20.        , -44.80853808],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 20.        ,  75.25228691],
       [-20.        , -38.40180557],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 20.        ,  79.79669393],
       [-20.        , -41.17248641],
       [ 20.        ,  47.30849516],
       [-20.        , -36.58623397],
       [ 20.        ,  72.49341592],
       [-20.        , -48.44571512],
       [ 20.        ,  78.33654527],
       [-20.        , -24.59730533],
       [ 15.        ,  52.4474551 ],
    ])
    assert np.allclose(expected, result, rtol=0, atol=1e-8)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()


Good point about max_buy not being used.  I reproduced a larger code into a more succinct code that captures the essence of the original code. In that process I missed using max_buy.  I will dit code per your suggestions and give it a try.  Thanks.
